# Why do I get two messages on `AltGr` being pressed?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, keyboard

Why do I get two messages on <kbd>AltGr</kbd> being pressed?

I have the following hook:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::KeyboardShotcutsHook(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

When in polish language I press <kbd>AltGR</kbd>+`Key` (<kbd>right Alt</kbd>) it produces 2 messages:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`Key`
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`Key`

Why? and how to avoid <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`Key`?

Answer (score 2):

Because AltGr and Alt+Ctrl are equivalent (in Windows). Two key stroke sequences mean the same thing, and Alt+Ctrl won (probably because there is no AltGr on the US keyboard layout - that's my guess).

If you want to check for AltGr, check if Ctrl is pressed whenever Alt shows up in your hook.

Comment: GetKeyState return 0 for VK_MENU VK_LMENU VK_RMENU for first "ctrl call". hm it problem only with polish language

Comment: @Kain: Here's some code that discusses the topic: http://gogglesmm.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fox-1.7/lib/fxkeyboard.cpp

Comment: Can you provide some authoritative source?

Comment: Nope, but I'm sure you could google it. I verified it by testing it in Windows and what keystrokes Windows itself generates when you hit AltGr.