# Strange Windows Message sequence of WM_KEYDOWN / WM_KEYUP while pressing VK_MENU (Alt key)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm pretty confused about `WM_KEY*` messages sequence when I'm pressing and releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (which is know in Virtual Key codes as `VK_MENU`).
When pressing right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key I get messages:

```
WM_KEYDOWN with wParam == 0x11 (VK_CONTROL)
WM_KEYDOWN with wParam == 0x12 (VK_MENU)
```

both messages one by one, when I'm releasing that key (right <kbd>Alt</kbd>) I get:

```
WM_KEYUP with wParam == 0x11 (VK_CONTROL)
WM_KEYUP with wParam == 0x12 (VK_MENU)
```

I was rather expecting:

```
WM_KEYDOWN with wParam == 0x12 (VK_MENU)
WM_KEYUP with wParam == 0x12 (VK_MENU)
```

Why there is `VK_CONTROL` involved in the message sequence if it wasn't touched at all? Is there some explanation?
*Edit: Some people marked this as a duplicate of [Why do I get two messages on <kbd>Alt</kbd> being pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094282/why-do-i-get-two-messages-on-altgr-being-pressed). Yes I agree it's a duplicate but somehow when I was trying to look for the answer giving keywords like `VK_CONTROL`, `VK_MENU`, `WM_KEYDOWN`, `Alt` etc. I couldn't find anything useful. Also not on every keyboard right Alt is marked as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>  depending on location (only OS keyboard setup matters) so it also is a keyword that you could have problem to figure out to look for. So I think it is good to have it explained in some other way.*

Comment: You are Polish, the standard keyboard layout in Poland has an AltGr key.  Located where other keyboards have the right-Alt key.  [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#Control_.2B_Alt_as_a_substitute).

Comment: @HansPassant that's worthy of an answer.

Comment: Somebody Polish ought to write that answer.  I don't have a keyboard like that.so can only guess that this is the underlying issue.  The OP is a good candidate.

Comment: Regarding your edit, that is the point of duplicates. They are an "alternate path" (hopefully a more search-friendly one) to the information. Don't fret that the question was marked as a duplicate. It doesn't mean you did anything wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make stackoverflow.com clear I rewrite an answer of [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) who put his answer as a comment.
I can confirm that on some keyboard layouts <kbd>Alt(right)</kbd> behaves like pushing together <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Also on one of keyboards that I'm using <kbd>Alt(right)</kbd> is tagged <kbd>AltGr</kbd> what is described in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key).
I can also confirm that changing keyboard layout to eg. US Native (not International) cause that only those

```
WM_KEYDOWN with wParam == 0x12 (VK_MENU)
WM_KEYUP with wParam == 0x12 (VK_MENU)
```

events are generated.
Thanks a lot [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant).